# Can anyone identify the software used to generate these illustrations?

Tags: windows, diagram

I really like the illustrations used on [this Microsoft MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Does anyone know of software that can be used to generate pictures like this?

[image: Example image]

Comment: I like the look of this too (+1). If no one tells you exactly which app was sued, are you open to suggestions of apps which will produce similar images?

Comment: @Mawg Absolutely! Even if there's anything comparable, I'd love to use such a tool. Balsamiq is the closest thing I can think of but I really like the style of these examples.

Comment: Tehre's a whole bunch of them, although not all will use the fancy font that looks like handwriting

Comment: Software identification is off-topic: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic You can make your question on-topic by modifying it to "*What software can create illustrations similar to this one?*" Please be sure to detail with words what is required, because different people see different things in an illustration. Example: "*It must 1) generate black and white 2) Export to PNG 3) Make each word's first letter uppercase*"

Comment: A very good point, @Nicolas. 
 
It's not really clear to me ***what*** the OP is asking for. Is it the font? Trying to make it had-drawn? Is it the exact constituent parts of the diagram, like the clipboard?  I address this in my comment to my answer below, but I would prefer to OP to tell us. Seamus, the more detailed information that you give us, the more that we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite diagramming app is [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). Check out [the gallery](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/gallery) to see if you like what it produces.

How about this, for example:

[image]

or this

[image]

or

[image]

There's even a subway train map

---

As an alternative to the drag & drop likes of Yed, [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), etc, I am a great fan of diagramming apps which take a plain text input and produce a diagram. And the undisputed king, for  a few decades now, is [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/). Again, take a look at [the gallery](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/), to see if you can find one that you like.

Here's a simple example, but you can get very complex if you want to.

This input:

```
graph G {
  e
  subgraph clusterA {
    a -- b;
    subgraph clusterC {
      C -- D;
    }
  }
  subgraph clusterB {
    d -- f
  }
  d -- D
  e -- clusterB
  clusterC -- clusterB
}
```

generates this diagram:

[image]

Comment: While these are all nice pieces of software, it doesn't look like that's what OP was asking for.

Comment: It's not really clear to me ***what*** the OP is asking for. Is it the font? Trying to make it had-drawn? If so, go for "wireframe", using something like one of [these](https://onextrapixel.com/40-brilliant-examples-of-sketched-ui-wireframes-and-mock-ups/). If the exact constituent parts of the diagram, like the clipboard, then yEd has many, but I ought to have stated one of the reasons I like ii is that you can import your own one time and they are thenceforth  available on the toolbar for use in future.

Comment: You are both correct. Let's wait for the asker to make the question on-topic.